# Does JBoss EAP include a reverse proxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, jboss

I am used to setup a reverse proxy in front of application servers like Node or Tomcat. Now I am required to use JBoss Enterprise Application Platform, but I don't know the platform. Is it advisable to deploy Nginx/Apache HTTP as reverse proxy in front of it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss EAP uses [Undertow](http://undertow.io/) as internal web server and it supports Reverse Proxy functionalities.

Red Hat documentation is accessible to partners and customers only, but you can dive into Wildfly Documentation, which is an upstream version of JBoss EAP.

- [Here you can find reference for use Wildlfy as a Reverse Proxy](https://docs.wildfly.org/19.1/Admin_Guide.html#using-wildly-as-a-static-load-balancer)
- [In this blog you can find a sample redirect rule](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/configuring-a-reverse-proxy-with-undertow)

That being said, I strongly suggest to **perform a load test on your Reverse Proxy implementation based on your load expectation**, because Undertow can performing less than an Nginx or Apache mod_proxy which are made for this very scope.